# createFileAtPath:contents:attributes storing a NSString

Tags: objective-c, c, nsfilemanager

The `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes` for Objective-C: `contents` requires an `NSData` type, but I want to create a file with a `NSString` content. How do I do this?

I know it's probably a really basic answer, but I'm just starting to learn how to use Objective-C, and it has so many different data types and objects compared to other languages I've used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try creating `NSData` with the content of the string, like this:

```
NSString *s = @"Hello, world!";
NSData *d = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can also store an `NSStrng` to a file directly:

```
[s writeToFile:@"/my/file/path/file.txt" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

**NOTE** This answer is edited after Ken Thomases's note.

Comment: Thanks. The second option looks best.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you can't use `-[NSString length]` in that way. It's the count of UTF-16 characters, not UTF-8 characters. Anyway, it's better not to use a C string as an intermediary. Just get the `NSData` directly from the string: `NSData *d = [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for the note, I edited the answer. I wasn't too certain about getting `NSData` through the internal content of the string, your way of getting the data is much better. I'm still relatively new to Objective-C, thanks for teaching me a new trick :)